# Hash functions not sensitive to element order

Tags: c, hash, sequence, hashset

I'm working with integer sequences with non-repeating elements, for some reasons I am tring to remove duplicates by building a hashset.

```
int * a = {123, 145, 210, 77};
int * b = {145, 77, 123, 210}; // should be removed
int * c = {123, 37, 16};
int * d = {123, 145, 72, 91};
```

Is there order insensitive hash functions that return same result for `a` and `b`?

I have come out of some solutions, but they performs poorly:

sorting - The sequences are immutable, sorting will invlove extra space and O(NlogN) time.

xor - The element in sequences ranges from 0 to hundreds, many bits of hash value may be wasted.

Is there other methods?

Comment: Probably a naive question: How about multiplying them?

Comment: What is the maximum value of a data item?

Comment: @PhilMasteG Every hash function has information loss, multiplying them would cause, for example, `{2, 3, 4}` and `{2, 2, 2, 3}` to have the same hash. Hashing alone is not enough.

Comment: An idea: multiply them (you probably need to take care of integer overflow) which results in A, then XOR them all which results in B, then XOR A and B which results in the hash.

Comment: To get more bits in the XOR hash, multiply each element by a large constant, and then XOR the product into the hash. For a 32-bit hash, a constant that's commonly used is `0xDEECE66D`. Multiplying by that constant results in a 1-to-1 mapping between one of the small integers and a 32-bit integer.

Comment: The largest value in your example is `210`. What is the actual range of values you need to handle? `INT_MIN`..`INT_MAX` or much smaller?

Comment: @Tenobaal Sure, this is an instance of an XY Problem. But the OP cited XOR as solution. I therefore summised, that multiplying would be just as fine for the specific question that was asked, which was "Are there other order insensitive hash functions?".

Comment: @PhilMasteG that is a valid hashing function, but it is not enough to find duplicate arrays. I was just pointing that out. For hashing I would either just add all the numbers or rotate the words based on their index and XOR the results.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is not the only thing you should do. Because of information loss, completely different arrays could return the same hash. In order to only remove duplicates, you would need to check for equivalence too. A hashset does that too, but places the elements based on a hash, so you can find them more easily.

Here is an example implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct hashset {
    int count;
    int capacity;
    struct hashset_element {
        int hash;
        int arrlen;
        int *arrval;
    } *elements;
};

void init_hashset(struct hashset *set) {
    set->count = 0;
    set->capacity = 0;
    set->elements = NULL;
}

int hash(int *arr, int len) {
    // you can replace this hash function
    // this is a pretty simple one
    int out = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        out += arr[i];
    }
    return out;
}

void arrequals(int *arr1, int len1, int *arr2, int len2) {
    if (len1 != len2)
        return false;
    arr1srt = sort(arr1, len1);
    arr2srt = sort(arr2, len2);
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        if (arr1srt[i] != arr2srt[i])
            free(arr1srt);
            free(arr2srt);
            return false;
    }
    free(arr1srt);
    free(arr2srt);
    return true;
}

bool hashset_contains(struct hashset *set, int *arr, int len) {
    int rawhash = hash(arr, len);
    int hash = rawhash % set->capacity;
    for (int i = hash; i < set->capacity; i++) {
        if (set->elements[i]->arrval == NULL)
            return false;
        if (arrequals(set->elements[i]->arrval,
        set->elements[i]->arrlen, arr, len)
            return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < hash; i++) {
        if (set->elements[i]->arrval == NULL)
            return false;
        if (set->elements[i]->hash == rawhash &&
        arrequals(set->elements[i]->arrval,
        set->elements[i]->arrlen, arr, len)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void hashset_realloc(struct hashset *set) {
    struct hashset_element* oldarr = set->elements;
    int old_capacity = set->capacity;
    set->elements = malloc(sizeof(struct hash_element) * set->capacity + 1024);
    set->capacity += 1024;
    for (int i = 0; i < set->capacity; i++) {
        if (oldarr[i]->arrval != NULL)
            hashset_add_element(set, oldarr[i]->arrval, oldarr[i]->arrlen);
    }
}

void hashset_add_element(struct hashset *set, int *arr, int len) {
    if (!hashset_contains(set, arr, len)) {
        if (set->count >= set->capacity / 2) {
            realloc_hashset(set);
        }
        int rawhash = hash_element(arr, len);
        int hash = rawhash % set->capacity;
        for (int i = hash; i < set->capacity; i++) {
             if (set->elements[i]->arrval == NULL) {
                 set->elements[i]->hash = rawhash;
                 set->elements[i]->arrval = arr;
                 set->elements[i]->arrlen = len;
                 set->count++;
                 return;
             }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < hash; i++) {
             if (set->elements[i]->arrval == NULL) {
                 set->elements[i]->hash = rawhash;
                 set->elements[i]->arrval = arr;
                 set->elements[i]->arrlen = len;
                 set->count++;
                 return;
             }
        }
    }
}

void destroy_hashset(struct hashset *set) {
    if (set->elements != NULL)
        free(set->elements);
}

int hashset_to_array(struct hashset *set, int **arrout, int *lenout, int maxlen) {
    int w = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        if (w >= maxlen)
            break;
        arrout[w] = set->elements[i]->arrval;
        lenout[w] = set->elements[i]->arrlen;
        w++;
    }
    return set->count;
}
```

I did not test this code, but give it a try and feel free to correct me, if there is an error in my code. You have to implement your sort function yourself. I don't know how big the arrays are, you are working with, so I can't pick an ideal algorithm for you. Order insensitive comparing is only possible in `O(n*log(n))`. `O(n)` is possible, if the integers have a maximum size, small enough to use a counting table.

In ideal cases this hashset has a runtime of `O(1)`. The worst case runtime is `O(n)`, which is very unlikely to happen. The hash algorithm has a runtime of `O(n)`, which is not ideal but okay for small arrays.